# ¿Puedo utilizar RabbitMQ para el encolamineto de correos electrónicos?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbit-mq

Estoy trabajando en Spring Boot. El escenario es el envío de correos electrónicos, lo cual se logró utilizando Apache Commons, pero el problema es que puedo tener uno u más remitentes, dado el caso que se tenga más de uno se debe repartir
la cantidad de correos a enviar entre los remitentes con lo que se cuenta de modo que cada remitente se encuentre trabajando y evitar una sobre carga de correos como sucede en gmail, pensaba en que podría utilizar RabbitMQ para lograr eso, pero desconozco si sea posible con esta herramienta, ¿alguna sugerencia de cómo lograr esto?

Answer (score 1):

Podría ser que tengas más de un consumer, de esa forma se reparte el trabajo.

De la página de RabbitMQ https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html#consuming

```
    boolean autoAck = false;
channel.basicConsume(queueName, autoAck, "myConsumerTag",
     new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
         @Override
         public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag,
                                    Envelope envelope,
                                    AMQP.BasicProperties properties,
                                    byte[] body)
             throws IOException
         {
             String routingKey = envelope.getRoutingKey();
             String contentType = properties.getContentType();
             long deliveryTag = envelope.getDeliveryTag();

             // aqui enviar el correo
             // body puede contener los datos necesarios para crear el correo

             channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, false);
         }
     });
```

Si tienes un servidor de RabbitMQ te puedes conectar al mismo queue desde diferentes lugares al mismo tiempo, y cada mensaje le llega solo a uno de los consumidores. Desde la app en Spring Boot se tendría que mandar el mensaje a RabbitMQ.